# How can I redirect and open content from a different directory to DocumentRoot in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, mod-alias

I've tried searching for my exact issue and couldn't find it. I don't want to redirect to a different domain, I merely want to achieve the equivalent of Alias in .htaccess. I'll explain what I have.

I'm using SiteGround cloud hosting and don't have access to anything other than .htaccess files. I have the following directory structure:

*/var/www/company.com
/var/www/microsite*

company.com contains a Drupal installation. I could create microsite as a sub-directory there but I want to keep the content and code separate.

On an in-house setup I have access to *sites-available* and have simply created an alias on "*/microsite-name*" "*/var/www/microsite*" and all is great -  *https://www.company.com/^* opens the main Drupal site, whilst if someone opens *https://www.company.com/microsite-name* content is loaded from */var/www/microsite*.

But with this cloud hosting, alias isn't allowed in .htaccess, so how do I achieve the same in .htaccess?

Thanks!